# java switch statements using label value

Tags: java

Can I refer to the selected case in switch statements within the case-block?

As clarification:

Assume we have a function `output(String)` which outputs a given string.

Can the old code then be transformed in some new code (which I do not know the correct syntax for)?

Old code:

```
public void switchTest(String string) {
    case "car":
        output("Car: car");
        break;
    case "cat": 
        output("Animal: cat");
        break;
    case "dog":
        output("Animal: dog");
        break;
    case "mouse":
        output("Animal: mouse");
        break;
    default:
        output("Unknown");
        break;
}
```

Proposed code, with `x` being our magical element:

```
public void switchTest(String string) {
    case "car":
        output("Car: " + x);
        break;
    case "cat":
    case "dog":
    case "mouse":
        output("Animal: " + x);
        break;
    default:
        output("Unknown");
        break;
}
```

ps. I am just using a hypothetical example, so don't worry if it makes no sense.

I hope it makes sense now, basicaly I want to refer to the value behind the case tag.

Regards.

Comment: Uhh well thanks for the answers. Just realised that I was thinking too difficult and not overseeing the big issue. Atleast thanks for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about

```
switch(string) {
   case "car":
        output("Car: " + string);
        break;
    case "cat":
    case "dog":
    case "mouse":
        output("Animal: " + string);
        break;
    default:
        output("Unknown");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if I'm missing the point here, but why not use string?

```
public void switchTest(String string) {
    case "car":
        output("Car: " + string);
        break;
    case "cat":
    case "dog":
    case "mouse":
        output("Animal: " + string);
        break;
    default:
        output("Unknown");
        break;
}
```

Comment: You are getting the point, I missed the point though :/ Well thanks :)